# Redirect using Window Location from Javascript Inside MVC Razor page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to redirect to a different page on submission of a form via javascript from an .Net MVC Razor page
The code i tried is  like below

```
$(function () {
var topSearch = '#navTopSearch';    
$(topSearch).submit(topSearch, redirectFromTopSearch);
$(topSearch + ' button').click(topSearch, redirectFromTopSearch);

function redirectFromTopSearch(event) {
  
  event.preventDefault(); 
  var link = '@Url.Action("Index", "MyCOntroller", new { IDNo = "replace" })';
  link = link.replace("replace", "12343");
  window.location = link;    
  //window.location.href = link;    
  return false;
```

}

});

But while executing on the form submission, i was getting a URL like this only

https://localhost:44320/@Url.Action(%22Index%22,%20%22MyCOntroller%22,%20new%20%7B%20IDNo%20=%20%2212343%22%20%7D)

How can I ensure that the application is redirecting to MyCOntroller/Index?IDNo=12343  correctly always. I have to ensure that this behavior is not changing on the server too( the solution is hosted inside a directory. NOt directly under the root folder )

After some more research , i found that the reason is because of  calling this from within .js file not Razor file

Comment: Why aren't you redirect manually? Like;
window.location = "/My/Index?IDNo=12343";

Comment: Managed to execute this by setting data attributes against select options like data-url=@Url.Action(**********) and then read them from js file